# Replace all the value except for the one a specified index of a numpy matrix with zero

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array

```
graph2 = [[0, 10, 15, 20],
        [10, 0, 35, 25],
        [15, 35, 0, 30],
        [20, 25, 30, 0]]
```

I want to replace all to zero except for values at a specific index.
Like Index (1,4), so the 20 at first line i don't place zero
(4,3) the 30 at fourth list, and (3,1) the 15 in third list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that list index **Starts at 1** not at 0. So your list indexes are wrong. I fixed them below

```
graph2 = [[0, 10, 15, 20],
        [10, 0, 35, 25],
        [15, 35, 0, 30],
        [20, 25, 30, 0]]
skip = [(0, 3), (3, 2), (2,0)]
for i in range(len(graph2)):
    for j in range(len(graph2[i])):
        if (i, j) in skip:
            continue
        else:
            graph2[i][j] = 0
print(graph2)
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the indices to skip are few, why not create a new numpy array of zeros and fill the values from the original array like:

```
newgraph = np.zeros(graph2.shape, dtype=np.int8)
indices = [[0, 3], [3, 2], [2, 0]]
for i, j in indices:
    newgraph[i,j] = graph2[i, j]
```

print(newgraph):

```
[[ 0  0  0 20]
 [ 0  0  0  0]
 [15  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 30  0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Noticed that you added the label of numpy. For numpy arrays, it is a best practice to pre create full zero array and assign values through fancy indices instead of using relatively slow for loop:

```
>>> graph2 = [[0, 10, 15, 20],
...         [10, 0, 35, 25],
...         [15, 35, 0, 30],
...         [20, 25, 30, 0]]
>>> indices = [[0, 3], [3, 2], [2, 0]]
>>> g = np.array(graph2)
>>> i, j = np.array(indices).T
>>> new = np.zeros(g.shape, g.dtype)
>>> new[i, j] = g[i, j]
>>> new
array([[ 0,  0,  0, 20],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [15,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 30,  0]])
```

However, it is expensive to build indices through transpose coordinate list, so you can consider writing the coordinate list in transpose form in advance:

```
>>> indices = np.array([0, 3, 2]), np.array([3, 2, 0])   # use tuple instead of list or ndarray
>>> new[indices] = g[indices]
```